# How to get method from generic Type in Java?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a problem like below:

```
List<T> someList;

for(T element : someList){
    System.out.println(element.getName()); //cannot resolve method 'getName'
}
```

how to get method from generic type?

my `T` is a class where I have many parameters with setters and getters,

can someone tell me how to `get` some params from `T` class?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

`T` needs to be upper-bounded to a type which has the `getName()` method.

For example:

```
interface HasGetName {
  String getName();
}
```

Then add your upper-bound using `T extends HasGetName`:

```
// If T is a class-level type variable:
class YourClass<T extends HasGetName> {
  List<T> someList;

  void print() {
    for(T element : someList){
      System.out.println(element.getName());
    }
  }
}

// If T is a method-class-level type variable:
class YourClass {
  <T extends HasGetName> void print(List<T> someList) {
    for(T element : someList){
      System.out.println(element.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would be something like:

```
List<T> someList;

for(T element : someList){
    if (element instanceof SpecializedElement)
        System.out.println(((SpecializedElement)element).getName());
}
```

Java 15 introduces something cool
List someList;

```
for(T element : someList){
    if (element instanceof SpecializedElement s)
        System.out.println(s.getName());
}
```

You don't need to do any casting with instanceof + class + any var name